# How can I get Eye of Gnome to open each figure in a new window?

Tags: window-manager, png, eog

I frequently open several (~10) figures that I want to compare.  I have always generated them using an `eps` format then used `evince` to open the set I want to compare using something like

```
evince set1*.eps &
```

Unfortunately my figures are getting too many features to effectively use `evince`, e.g., 100000 circles.  I can just as easily generate them as a raster image, e.g., `png`, but when I open them using Eye of Gnome, it uses the same window for each one which does not work for comparing

```
eog set1*.png &
```

I know I can run something like

```
eog set1*1.png &
eog set1*2.png &
eog set1*3.png & 
...
```

but is there a simple bash command to get a separate window for each?  I did not find anything on the [Gnome help page](https://help.gnome.org/users/eog/stable/commandline.html.en).

Comment: You can always just run it all in one line: `eog set1*1.png & eog set1*2.png & eog set1*3.png...`

Comment: I realize that but I am looking for something more simple that works well with wild cards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple loop could do the trick:

```bsh
for i in set1*.png; do eog -n "$i" & done
```

Comment: This is perfect!  This essentially duplicates the functionality I like about `eps` files and `evince`.

Comment: @stvn66 you could make a function and add it to your `.bashrc`: `eogn () { for i; do eog -n "$i"; done; }`, and then call `eogn set1*.png`.

Comment: The `eogn` as written opens them one at a time.  I tried adding an `&` but that did not work.  I'm sure I could put it in a bash script but as is, the solution is  not too much to type I think.

Comment: @stvn66 ah, yes, it should have been `eog -n "$i" & done; }`, though I'm not sure why it didn't work after you corrected that.

Comment: That works.  I forgot to remove the `;` and only changed it to `eog -n "$i" &; done; } .  This is great, thanks!